# fonts of a word in Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word

Do you guys know how can I make the font of "C" in the figure below similar to others? It seems the bold is not applied for "C", but could not find out any reason why it looks so.

[image]

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums. If you do post something there, you should add a link in your question here to the new question here to help others.

Answer (score 1):

Check text color (the other characters look to be gray rather than black) and make sure that they are all in fact the same font.

Comment: Thanks, it worked out.